# Pregunta sobre funcionamiento de chart js

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

Estoy empezando a utilizar chart js y la verdad no se utilizarlo, ya lo instale con npm install chart.js --save y lo estoy tratando de probar con estos datos de prueba:

```
 <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
    import Chart from 'chart.js';
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [10, 20, 30]
            }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

pero el buscador me dice que ctx no esta definido, no se que pueda estar mal, ¿alguien que me pueda iluminar?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [10, 20, 30]
        }]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

La variable ctx es el [contexto del canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext), lo correcto sería obtenerlo antes de intentar generar el gráfico, algo como

Comment: Si el error le da en la variable ctx, creo que el import le funciona

Comment: ahora tengo otros dos errores, que son: GET http://dev.unadeca_evaluations.com/path/to/chartjs/dist/Chart.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
 y que getContest es nulo

Comment: getConte**x**t, no getConte**s**t

Comment: perdon, me equivoque al escribirlo aqui, pero en codigo si esta bien escrito y ya resolvi el primer problema ahora solo queda el de getContext